# iPhone OS: How do I create an NSDate for a specific date?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

Seems like a simple thing but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

It would be great to see a couple different methods.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

@Chuck's answer is correct, and lead me to the following code. Thought I'd share:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:10];
[comps setMonth:10];
[comps setYear:2010];
NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Comment: Note there is also `setHour`, `setMinute`, `setSecond`, etc. for finer granularity.

Answer (score 22):

You can use this

```
NSString *dateString = @"03-Sep-11";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yy";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Be careful using the "dateFromString" function - I found that with some perfectly-valid dates, it'd fail miserably.  See my post below for an alternative way of parsing date strings.

Comment: The way Oded Ben mention is also another best way.....
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:10];
[comps setMonth:10];
[comps setYear:2010];
NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

Comment: This code will fail if the app is localized to a language where the month name doesn't match. You should also use a 4-digit year to be clear.

Answer (score 17):

If you're talking about a specific calendar date rather than a UNIXy date, you probably want NSCalendar's `dateFromComponents:`.

Answer (score 12):

## Swift Examples

Examples are often the easiest way to learn. Here are a few examples.

## Now

This one is the easiest.

```
let currentDateTime = Date()
```

## February 20, 2017

```
// Specify date components
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.year = 2017
dateComponents.month = 2
dateComponents.day = 20

// Create date from components
let userCalendar = Calendar.current // user calendar
let dateThisPostWasUpdated = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)
```

## April 1, 1976

```
// Specify date components
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.year = 1976
dateComponents.month = 4
dateComponents.day = 1

// Create date from components
let userCalendar = Calendar.current // user calendar
let appleFoundedDate = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)
```

## Need more details...?

There are other ways to create dates, too. If you want to learn those, as well as how to *display* a date, then [see my fuller answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33343958/3681880).

Answer (score 9):

See the documentation for [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can use the [`dateFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:) method of `NSDateFormatter` or the [`dateFromComponents:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateFromComponents:) method of `NSCalendar`.

Comment: I keep getting this date : "1969-12-31 16:00:00" -0800 when using date from string

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *capturedStartDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"Jan 2, 2001"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [capturedStartDate description]);


output:

    2010-04-05 10:49:47.688 Calendar2[21339:207] 1969-12-31 16:00:00 -0800

Comment: Maybe you need to set some parameters on the date formatted instead of plain `init`?

Answer (score 4):

I found this thread while looking for an answer to this question but then I found a good example in one my Big Nerd Ranch Objective-C Programming book.  Credit to them, not me.

```
  NSDateComponents *myBDay  =[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [myBDay setDay:22];
    [myBDay setMonth: 04];
    [myBDay setYear: 1984];
    [myBDay setHour:9];
    [myBDay setMinute:25];
    [myBDay setSecond:35];

    NSCalendar *g = [[ NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDate *dateOfBirth = [g dateFromComponents:myBDay];
```

Answer (score 2):

It is ridiculous, isn't it ?

Mid-2013 and Apple *still* hasn't provided a simple way to set a NSDate value.

During my current iPad project, I couldn't believe I had to stop productivity for a while to write my own helper class to get the Year value from an NSDate.   I mean, come on, this is basic stuff.

Anyway, here's the helper class I used in my project, to convert a string into an NSDate value :

```
@implementation DateHelper

+(NSDate*)parseDateString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];

    NSDate *theDate = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone getObjectValue:&theDate forString:dateString range:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Date '%@' could not be parsed: %@", dateString, error);
    }

    return theDate;
}

@end
```

Using this code, you could set an NSDate value using something like:

```
NSDate* date = [DateHelper parseDateString:@"Jul 16, 2013"];
```

Note:  this function was based on code taken from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3968411/391605

My solution *had been* to use the following code, but I found that *sometimes*, it just wouldn't parse, and would return *nil*.

```
//  Take a date string in the format "Oct 23, 2013", and convert it into a NSDate value
//  THIS DOESN'T WORK !  DON'T TRUST THIS CODE !!
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

I remember it failed miserably on "Oct 12, 2012"...  which is why I gave up and used the more complicated "parseDateString" function shown above.

My point is... be careful.

Some of the very-basic NSDate functions just don't work properly...

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this in Objective-C. It's not efficient but simple.

```
+(NSDate *) MakeNSDate : (int) year : (int) month : (int) day : (int) hour : (int) min : (int) sec
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dtRet = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4d/%02d/%2d %02d:%02d:%02d", year, month, day, hour, min, sec]];
    return dtRet;
}
```