# Parsing date in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

How can I parse this into an objective-c NSDate most efficiently?

"2010-07-13T11:22:33-07:00"

This is what I tried

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

but did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094819/nsdateformatter-returning-nil-in-os-4-0), i had that issue

"The format that I am being given is halfway between RFC 822 and GMT. if i change the "+00:00" to "+0000" then I can use the "Z" on my format. and if i change it to "GMT+00:00" then I can use ZZZZ to get the data properly. It seems that something has been stripped out to handle this hybrid as it was working for me before with OS 3.x"