# NSDateFormatter return nil in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, nsdateformatter

With iOS 6 everything is ok but with iOS 5 myDate return nil

```
NSString *dateString = @"2012-07-12T11:00:00+02:00";

NSLocale *deLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_DE"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
dateFormatter.locale = deLocale;
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

It must be a Problem with the DateFormat i believe

Comment: The problem is with the `:` in the time zone information. This is not support by the `NSDateFormatter`. This has been asked before. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094819/nsdateformatter-returning-nil-in-os-4-0

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
 NSLog(@"Date: %@", dateString);
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/12/2012 12:12:12 AM"]);
```

Comment: Great that it work for you, but the date that you parse does not match the on given by @TimoP