# dateFromString working in ios6 but not in ios5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know there is a lot of threads on this subject and I have read them all.

In my particular case when tested on the iPhone 6.1 Simulator dateFromString is working flawlessly but returns null on iPhone 5.1 Simulator. I have also tested it on several devices with iOS6 and iOS5 getting to the same conclusion.

The format in 'input' being: 2013-02-15T18:00:00+03:00

I wrote the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+zz:zz"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:input];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE'. 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy', 'HH':'mm"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
return stringFromDate;
```

... to obtain in stringFromDate "Fri. 15 Feb 2013, 18:00" on iOS6 and "null" on iOS5 on both simulators and devices.

Please help me

Comment: Why are you setting the `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:...]` twice?

Comment: I am using the same dateFormatter to change the format to the new one after converting the input String into a NSDate

Comment: Oh, okay. After some research I've found a possible like that deals with changes to the location the user (or the simulator simulates) is located. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link!
Unfortunately I have tried all what's said there, I still get the same result... 
PS: Both 6.1 and 5.1 simulators are on the same XCode installation (hence both have the same system Time and Date settings)

Comment: Any clue? I'm still stuck

Comment: Seems to a problem with the `:` in the formatter. Check this question and the answer in the first comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413600/nsdateformatter-return-nil-in-ios-5

Comment: Thank you, this thread lead me to another one which helped me:
I was able to solve it by using the following lines of code:

    NSDate *theDate = nil;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![dateFormatter getObjectValue:&theDate forString:input range:nil error:&error]) {}

Answer (score 1):

It's not iOS5  or iOS 6 issue. Please **check about time format set in setting** whether it is 12-hour format or 24-hour format.

It will solve your problem

Comment: Dear Vijay, Thank you for your quick reply.

I have tried it on a device, it still returns me null on iOS5, and concerning the simulators I think the Mac OS X system settings are taken into account; there is no Date & Time option in the General pane of the Settings.