# Using NSDateFormatter in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I would like to convert `2013-07-10T21:48:09.000Z` to `10.7.2013` using `nsdateformatter`.

I've tried going through some tutorial but I can't seem to figure out what to do, How would I correctly do this conversion?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried this but I only get returned a `(null)`

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:000Z"];
    NSDate *theDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:theDate]);
```

Comment: please link to the tutorial you used

Comment: Have a look here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094819/nsdateformatter-returning-nil-in-os-4-0

Comment: There's a seconds part missing in your format.

Comment: What part am I missing ?

Comment: `Z` needs to have quotes around it if you want it to be a literal "Z", because `Z` is used as a timezone format character.

Comment: Read the spec for NSDateFormatter.  And follow the links in there through the several pages to where the format strings are described.  Then search SO for the literally thousands of questions about NSDateFormatter, written by previous folks who, like you, failed to do this fundamental research.

Comment: In your above code snippet did you do the minimal amount of debugging required to see if you're getting a good result from the `dateFromString` operation, to divide your problem in half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your date format is wrong -- the second line should be `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z"];` -- that is, you need the `ss.` after the `mm:` but before the `000Z`. This will give you the correct NSDate.

Next, you need to create a new date formatter with the format `@"dd.M.yyyy"` (or `@"d.M.yyyy"` if you want to remove the leading zero if the *day* is a single digit as well) and call `stringFromDate:` on that for the NSLog.

Just to recap, the whole chunk of code would be

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z"];
NSDate *theDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

NSDateFormatter *printFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[printFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.M.yyyy"];
NSLog(@"%@",[printFormatter stringFromDate:theDate]);
```

Comment: It returned '2013-07-10T21:48:09.000+0000', I need it to return '10.7.2013'

Comment: @IamGretar Oops, didn't catch that -- I thought you just wanted the correct NSDate. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Doesn't need to be a new NSDateFormatter -- simply set a new format into the old one.

Comment: @HotLicks Good point, that works as well (and saves you the trouble of allocating another ```NSDateFormatter``` instance).