# Realm query 'where before date'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, realm

I've just discovered **Realm** and started working with it in **objective-c**.

I'm trying to get the objects **where** `create_date` **before** `specific date and time`

I read [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291286/realm-date-query#30292184), So i tried this :

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-06-03 08:24:00";
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
NSString *_where = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"create_date < '%@'", newDate];
RLMResults *results = [database_articles objectsInRealm:realm where:_where];
```

but i'm getting the following error:

> 'Expected object of type date for property 'created' on object of type 'database_articles', but received: 2015-06-03 05:24:00 +0000'

So how can I pass **NSDATE** in a **query** in **Realm** ??

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used the method `+ (RLMResults *)objectsInRealm:(RLMRealm *) where:(NSString *), ...;`, which is a convenience API, taking a string and further arguments and constructing a `NSPredicate` from it on-the-fly for you. By providing your arguments first to `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, you serialize your date, so that it comes to this error.

Use one of those two variants to avoid that:

```
RLMResults *results = [database_articles objectsInRealm:realm where:@"create_date < %@", newDate];
```

---

```
NSPredicate *_where = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"create_date < %@", newDate];
RLMResults *results = [database_articles objectsInRealm:realm withPredicate:_where];
```

Comment: but i should be like this
`NSPredicate *_where = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"created < %@", newDate];`

`RLMResults *results = [database_articles objectsInRealm:realm withPredicate:_where];`

Comment: Also you need to remove the **Quotation Marks** around **%@**